# Triangle and Circle maximization problem

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization, circles, triangles

So I was playing around GeoGebra and found this thing out, I don't know if this problem has a name or something.

Triangle ABC is inscribed inside a circle, from point D which is located inside the circle, we draw 3 perpendicular lines to each side of the triangle, what is the maximum area of the triangle whose vertices are the intersections of the perpendicular lines and the sides of the triangle? (maximum area of triangle EFG, the red triangle in the picture)

Using Geogebra I found out that this area is always maximal when point D is located at the center of the circle, or in other words, when the perpendiculars divide the sides into 2 equal segments.

If someone could provide a proof/explain why, I would be grateful.

See the diagram below:

[image]

Comment: A synthetic proof here seems like a real bastard, I must say!

Comment: When $D$ is the circumcentre of $ABC$ the perpendiculars are also the bisector of the sides of $ABC$ and $EFG$ is similar to $ABC$ and it is exactly $\dfrac{1}{4}$ of its area. Left to prove that any other position leads to smaller triangles

Comment: @Raffaele I think you've left the hard bit!

Comment: The [medial triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_triangle) is formed as you specify by connecting midpoints. The concurrence of these perpendicular lines must be important, since a freely chosen set of points on the sides could have area arbitrarily close to the full triangle area. I'm less convinced that the restriction to the circle is important.

Comment: At first I restricted the point D to be INSIDE the triangle, the answer was also the circumcenter, aka the median triangle, but then I remembered that the circumcenter could be outside the triangle, so I tried it with the triangle in the picture and apparently if you move the point D anywhere you want in the plane you can have areas up to infinity( as the points EGF lie on the extensions of the sides of the triangles ABC) 
So there must be some restriction on the placement of the point D which i assumed is the circumcircle, if there's no restriction, then the circumcenter is a local maximum

Comment: Here's what I meant that if the point D goes outside the Circle (anywhere in the plane) you can get areas up to infinity:
http://imgur.com/X55rq7j

Comment: UPDATE: managed to proof that if D lies on the circle (not inside, nor outside), then the points E,G,F lie on one line, in other words, when D lies ON the circle, the area of the triangle EGF is 0
So basically we have that the circumcenter is a local maximuim, the area of the red triangle starts to decrease as the point D goes further away from the circumcenter, once point D becomes ON the circle, the area becomes 0, then as I keep going further away the area starts to increase once again, up to infinity
Atleast now we know how the point D behaves, now we have to prove the local maximum

Comment: UPDATE 2: Wow, via geogebra, the area of the red triangle depends ONLY on the distance of the point D from the circumcenter, so for the set of all points D which have the same fixed distance from the circumcenter, the red area is equal through all these points!
So according to geogebra, let's assume that the distance from D to the circumcenter is X, and the radius of the circle in the picture is r
If X increases while X<r, the area decreases
and when x=r the area is 0
If you increase X while X>r, the area keeps increasing (up to infinity)

Comment: Very interesting result

Answer (score 3):

$+1$ for re-discovering this neat property of [pedal triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedal_triangle): the area is proportional to the power of the point with respect to the circumcircle, in other words it only depends on the distance from the point to the circumcenter of the original triangle:

$$
S_{EFG}=\frac{R^2-OD^2}{4 R^2} \,S_{ABC}
$$

[Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PedalTriangle.html) quotes on this *Johnson, R. A. Modern Geometry: [An Elementary Treatise on the Geometry of the Triangle and the Circle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006AKOR8). Boston, MA: Houghton Mifflin, 1929*.

A proof can be found for example on [cut-the-knot](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/PedalTriangle.shtml).

Comment: Wow, this explains everything!  Thank you! 
The problem looks difficult to solve if one did not know that the area depends only on the distance from D to the circumcenter and the area of the original triangle ABC